# How to invoke WinWait for silent installation of wizard to support multiple languages?

Tags: shell, automation, macros, autohotkey, wine

I'm using `winetricks` to perform silent install of wizard and I've got the following code which works fine (based on [previous version of installer](https://github.com/Winetricks/winetricks/commit/774a45b6fd22d8b6ea1384144f11b2a1698ee69c)):

```
w_ahk_do "
    Run, ${file1}
    WinWait, MetaTrader 5 Setup
    ControlClick, Button1
    Sleep 100
    ControlClick, Button3
    WinWait, MetaTrader 5 Setup, Installation successfully completed
    ControlClick, Button4
    Process, Wait, terminal.exe
    Process, Close, terminal.exe
"
```

However the problem is that it doesn't work when locale is different.

So then I've to adjust the code accordingly to the language, for example the Polish version would look like:

```
w_ahk_do "
    Run, ${file1}
    WinWait, MetaTrader 5 Ustawienia
    ControlClick, Button1
    Sleep 100
    ControlClick, Button3
    WinWait, MetaTrader 5 Ustawienia, Instalacja ukończona
    ControlClick, Button4
    Process, Wait, terminal.exe
    Process, Close, terminal.exe
"
```

and so on.

Is there any method to prevent implementing many different codes for each language (using [`WinWait`](https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/WinWait.htm) or similar function)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    ; auto-execute section:
; GroupAdd, GroupName, WinTitle, WinText, Label, ExcludeTitle, ExcludeText

GroupAdd, MetaTrader_Setup_Group, MetaTrader 5 Setup,,,, Installation successfully completed
GroupAdd, MetaTrader_Setup_Group, MetaTrader 5 Ustawienia,,,, Instalacja ukończona

GroupAdd, MetaTrader_Setup_successfull_Group, MetaTrader 5 Setup, Installation successfully completed
GroupAdd, MetaTrader_Setup_successfull_Group, MetaTrader 5 Ustawienia, Instalacja ukończona

        Return  ; ênd of the auto-execute section

; All windowing commands can operate upon a window group by specifying ahk_group GroupName

w_ahk_do "
    Run, ${file1}
    WinWait, ahk_group MetaTrader_Setup_Group
    ControlClick, Button1
    Sleep 100
    ControlClick, Button3
    WinWait, ahk_group MetaTrader_Setup_successfull_Group
    ControlClick, Button4
    Process, Wait, terminal.exe
    Process, Close, terminal.exe
"
```

https://autohotkey.com/docs/commands/GroupAdd.htm

---

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use [`WinWait, ahk_class`](https://hotkeyit.github.io/v2/docs/commands/WinWait.htm), e.g.

```
WinWait, ahk_class MetaQuotes::MetaTrader::4.00
```

To get the name of the AHK class, `WindowSpy.ahk` script can be used (shipped with AHK).